# Expo SDK 46 throwing CMAKE error when syncing Gradle

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, cmake, expo

I am have managed to replicate this across 3 different repos. I am trying to sync the gradle project in Android studio from a bare Expo project but I keep getting his with the below error

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
FBJNI_LIB
linked by target "expo-modules-core" in directory /Users/sebsmith/test-cmake/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android
FOLLY_LIB
linked by target "expo-modules-core" in directory /Users/sebsmith/test-cmake/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android
JSEXECUTOR_LIB
linked by target "expo-modules-core" in directory /Users/sebsmith/test-cmake/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android
JSI_LIB
linked by target "expo-modules-core" in directory /Users/sebsmith/test-cmake/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android
REACT_NATIVE_JNI_LIB
linked by target "expo-modules-core" in directory /Users/sebsmith/test-cmake/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android
REACT_NATIVE_MODULES_CORE
linked by target "expo-modules-core" in directory /Users/sebsmith/test-cmake/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android
```

I have ran `expo install` && `expo-cli doctor --fix-dependencies` and all modules are up to date.

**Replicable Steps**

```
npx create-expo-app test-cmake
cd test-cmake
rm yarn.lock
npm install
expo install
npx expo prebuild
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I am hitting the same error. I know the latest version of Expo is incompatible with the current React Native version, 0.70.0. It would break whenever trying to sync my gradle files, yet it worked building the app on iOS. This means the current expo has issues with Java / Android, so this may just be another and we need to wait on an update. Looking for a fix still in the meantime

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary solution, but going into your `package.json` and downgrading `expo-modules-core` to version 9.2 This gave me a few errors with other Expo packages that were expecting a higher version of `expo-modules-core` (`VisionCamera` for some reason is one that comes to mind) so bear that in mind when attempting this solution. If not, just wait until there's an update to `expo-modules-core`